# Ubuntu, User Accounts messed up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, user, sudo

I need to fix Ubuntu Accounts somehow but I don't really see how it could be done.

The problem is: 
files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` where changed.

## /etc/passwd

Before

```
serg:x:1000:1000:John,,,:/home/serg:/bin/bash
```

After

```
John:x:1000:1000:John,,,:/home/serg:/bin/bash
```

## /etc/hosts

Before

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       serg-Protege
```

After

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       John-The-Ripper
```

## /etc/hostname

After

```
John-The-Ripper
```

Before

```
serg-PORTEGE-Z835
```

I was trying to simply change these files but can not do this because permission denied. 
When I'm trying to log in as root, I got this message:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for John: 
John is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported
```

The file sudoers is empty:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$  vi /etc/sudoers
```

When I type users in cp:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ users
John John
```

When I type id, I got this:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ id
uid=1000(John) gid=1000(serg) groups=1000(serg)
```

This doesn't work eather:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ usermod -l John serg
usermod: user 'serg' does not exist
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ adduser serg
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
ater.
```

Then I tried to go to the GRUB menu and log in as root from there. I did this, but however When I tried to create user serg, It gave me an error that group already exists. When I tried to change /etc/passwd it said 'permission denied'

And this doesn't do the trick:
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ visudo

```
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Also The last thing I tried to do is to create a bootable USB and reinstall ubuntu, however I can not open USB-Creator because it asked me a root password. But it doesn't work.

HELP ME PLEASE =)))

Comment: A bit off topic, but if you add "John" to the line in `/etc/group` that most likely now says `sudo:x:27:serg`, you should be able to sudo again. Alternately, remove the line that says `serg:x:1000` or similar from the same file and you should be able to once again create the `serg` user. When you're root again, just add `John` to all lines in `/etc/group` that now say `serg` and all should be back to normal.

Comment: It's not working, I can not change these file because 'Error writing group: Permission denied'

Comment: This is not a programming question; you should ask it on a more appropriate site such as askubuntu.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you no longer have root access, so you don't have permission to change those files.  The `/etc/sudoers` file checks your user name, not your numeric UID; it probably still refers to user "serg" rather than user "John". And Ubuntu generally doesn't have a password for the `root` account, depending instead on `sudo`, which requires your password, not root's.

Shut down your system, then boot it into single-user mode. This will give you a shell with root privileges. From there, you can *carefully* edit the necessary files. (To state the obvious, be careful; it's easy to trash your system from a root shell.) Double-check that everything is back to the way you want it (no typos), then reboot into normal mode.

[See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73442/how-do-i-login-in-single-user-mode) for instructions on booting into single-user mode.